# Is it possible to safely destructure an ES6 React Component class in its constructor signature?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have an ES6 class which extends `React.Component`, i.e. a React component. Let's say my component looks like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor({ foo, bar, baz, ...props }) {
    super({ foo, bar, baz, ...props });
    this.state = { foo, bar, baz };
  }

  render() {
     return <span>Foo: {this.state.foo} Bar: {this.state.bar} Baz: {this.state.baz}</span>
  }
}
```

Here I am using destructuring in the signature of the constructor to pull out some props I would like to use in my component's state. I ensure I pass those values to super. However, when I actually execute similar code I see a warning that looks like this:

> Warning: MyComponent(...): When calling super() in `MyComponent`, make
>   sure to pass up the same props that your component's constructor was
>   passed.

So my question is if it is possible to destructure the constructor's signature like I have shown without the associated warning? (I'm assuming the warning is there for good reason and I'm equally sure I don't fully understand the implications.)

Comment: pretty sure it's because `super` is the first thing you have to call in a function, but if you're transpiling with babel, in order to use destructuring it has to do `const foo = props.foo` etc. before the super call. What you can do instead is `super(props)` and then `const { foo, bar, baz } = props` after the super call.

Comment: Of course I realize I can do that, but that's not what I asked. The example code I gave above does in fact bind values correctly for me, but I am concerned about the warning if somehow the same props are not percolating up through super.

Comment: The warning might also be that you're constructing a clone of the object that was passed in. I assume the warning is a shallow equality check against the original props (because a deep one would be too expensive), and so while you're passing the right stuff in you're still getting warned. Pretty sure what you're doing is fine, but the reason I'm writing this is comments it that I'm too lazy to go check out the `React` source code on github :p

Comment: Thank you @AR7, that makes sense to me. I would be happy to accept that as an answer if you would like to type it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[If you look at this line in the React source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/ef99e7e096cb661de0e72f93a442fbfeaaa07b1c/src/renderers/shared/stack/reconciler/ReactCompositeComponent.js#L243), you'll see it does a shallow check to see if the props objects match up.

```
// other stuff

var propsMutated = inst.props !== publicProps;

// other stuff

warning(
  inst.props === undefined || !propsMutated,
  '%s(...): When calling super() in `%s`, make sure to pass ' +
  'up the same props that your component\'s constructor was passed.',
  componentName, componentName
);
```

You created a clone of the props when you passed it into super so it raises the warning.